# After insert not updating the fields from contact BATCH CLASS [TRIGGER]

Tags: apex, trigger

**CLASS**

```
global class ModifiedDate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
List<Contact> ctt = new List<Contact>();
String query= '[SELECT Id,Name,Phone,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate,LastContact__c,(SELECT Id,AccountId,Name,Phone FROM Contacts) FROM Account]';
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
    //code to do
    for(Account acc: scope){
        if(acc.CreatedDate > acc.LastModifiedDate){
            acc.LastContact__c = acc.CreatedDate;
            for(Contact ctct: acc.Contacts){
                ctct.Phone = acc.Phone;
                ctt.add(ctct);
            }

        }
        update ctt;
        update acc;
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    //code to do when the batch job finished
    System.debug('>>>>> Finish Execution: ' + System.now().format());
}}
```

**TRIGGER**

```
trigger AccountModifiedDate_Trigger on Account (after insert){
    ModifiedDate modifiedDateBatchClass = new ModifiedDate();
    ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(modifiedDateBatchClass);
}
```

Comment: Hello, analyzing the code makes me believe that it will do nothing other than execute a query. Maybe if you can explain what you are trying to achieve we can do a better job at providing some guidance. Maybe add the other trigger that creates the contacts?

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if(acc.CreatedDate > acc.LastModifiedDate){` looks suspect. I don't think the CreatedDate would ever be greater than the LastModifiedDate.

Also:

1. You should investigation bulkification of triggers. You don't want to be performing DML operations in the for loop.
2. The batch process could be made more selective to only interact with the Accounts that were present in the trigger. Otherwise you are needlessly revisiting every Account in the Org.
3. An Account that has just been inserted won't have any Contacts. The Contacts can't be inserted until the Account has been.

Comment: but  do you think the statement below will run?

Comment: i have a seperate trigger for creating contacts

Comment: No, I don't think it will every run as the condition will never be true. You might be better served by a Workflow rule or similar to default the LastContact__c field.